# Close dialog onclick close icon in alertify.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertifyjs

I am useing alertify dialog and I have added a close icon in the dialog as follows

```
<span class='close-button' id='closebutton'></span>
```

I am trying to close the dialog onclicking the closing the close icon as follows. But I am facing an error as " cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' closebutton is not defined."  and unable to close the dialog. Please let me know if there is any solution. Thanks in advance.

```
 $("#closebutton").on( 'click', function () {  $('#submitdialog').dialog('close');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name of your dialog to access the close method:

First create the dialog:

```
alertify.dialog('myAlert',function(){
return{
  main:function(message){
    this.message = message;
  },
  setup:function(){
      return { 
        buttons:[{text: "cool!", key:27/*Esc*/}],
        focus: { element:0 }
      };
  },
  prepare:function(){
    this.setContent(this.message);
  }
```

}});

Then you can close it in this way:

```
//close it
alertify.myAlert().close()
```

Notice that myAlert is the name of the dialog.